# How do I check if an object has given keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

how do I Check if an Object hast the given keys, both attributes and their type ?

```
const requiredKeys = {title: 'string', type: ['image', 'video', 'website'], src: 'string'};
const optionalKeys = {description: 'string', views: 'number', ranking: 'number'};
const internalKeys = {id: 'number', timestamp: 'number'};
```

Comment: A loop, `typeof` and a comparison.

Comment: You haven't specified what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: ok sorry for not being clear, i have an object and need to check if it has all attributes  and the right types of values in there (right meaning the form of requiredKeys),  is there a simple way to check if it does using the "requiredKeys" object

Comment: By the choice of your "requiredKeys", I suspect you are working with dom objects. If that is the case, you can use "hasAttribute" method and use "typeof" over the values to check its' type. If that is not the case, then just use "hasOwnProperty" for checking the keys and "typeof" to check its' type.